# How to optimize view with group by

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, performance, postgresql-performance

Have view with query :

```
SELECT min(lbl.id) AS id, lb.order_id, lb.par_id, lbl.lb_id, lb.categ_id, lbl.mt_id, lbl.uom_id, lbl.tracking_id,
 sum(lbl.orig_qty) AS orig_qty, max(lbl.qty) AS qty, sum(lbl.rch_qty) AS rch_qty, sum(lbl.rsrv_qty) AS rsrv_qty, 
 min(lbl.date_qty) AS date_qty, min(lbl.date_rchqty) AS date_rchqty, max(lbl.sequence) AS sequence, max((lbl.state)::text) AS state, 
 max(lbl.comment) AS comment, array_to_string(array_agg(lbl.id), ','::text) AS mat_ids 
 FROM tbl1 lb 
    JOIN tbl2 lbl ON lb.id = lbl.laborder_id
    JOIN tbl2 prd ON lbl.mt_id = prd.id
 GROUP BY lb.order_id, lb.par_id, lbl.lb_id, lb.categ_id, lbl.mt_id, lbl.uom_id, lbl.tracking_id;
```

Total runtime of the query is  2658.875 ms
Explain anayze plan when work_mem = 1 mb is :

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=105065.17..127333.04 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=1376.793..2636.413 rows=202404 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=105065.17..105955.88 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=1376.753..1491.741 rows=356286 loops=1)
         Sort Key: lb.order_id, lb.par_id, lbl.lb_id, lb.categ_id, lbl.mt_id, lbl.uom_id, lbl.tracking_id
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 27336kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=92.77..38106.83 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=1.498..826.742 rows=356286 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (lbl.mt_id = prd.id)
               ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.81..32670.59 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=0.035..671.049 rows=356286 loops=1)
                     Merge Cond: (lb.id = lbl.lorder_id)
                     ->  Index Scan using tbl1_pkey on tbl1 lb  (cost=0.00..10545.07 rows=186136 width=16) (actualtime=0.015..105.777 rows=186136 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using tbl2_lorder_id_index on tbl2 lbl  (cost=0.00..17206.72 rows=356286 width=77) (actual time=0.009..219.785 rows=356286 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=64.82..64.82 rows=2171 width=4) (actual time=1.441..1.441 rows=2171 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 77kB
                     ->  Index Only Scan using tbl2_pkey on tbl2 prd  (cost=0.00..64.82 rows=2171 width=4) (actual time=0.089..0.659 rows=2171 loops=1)
                           Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 2658.875 ms
(15 rows)
```

When work_mem = 200 mb

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=63667.22..85935.09 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=1057.591..2247.091 rows=202404 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=63667.22..64557.93 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=1057.553..1105.126 rows=356286 loops=1)
         Sort Key: lb.order_id, lb.par_id, lbl.lb_id, lb.categ_id, lbl.mt_id, lbl.uom_id, lbl.tracking_id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 62432kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=8321.01..30812.88 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=122.309..673.887 rows=356286 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (lbl.mt_id = prd.id)
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=8229.06..25376.64 rows=356286 width=85) (actual time=121.224..534.207 rows=356286 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (lbl.lorder_id = lb.id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on tbl2 lbl  (cost=0.00..10021.86 rows=356286 width=77) (actual time=0.003..70.330 rows=356286 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=5902.36..5902.36 rows=186136 width=16) (actual time=121.065..121.065 rows=186136 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8725kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on tbl1 lb  (cost=0.00..5902.36 rows=186136 width=16) (actual time=0.039..71.138 rows=186136 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=64.82..64.82 rows=2171 width=4) (actual time=1.075..1.075 rows=2171 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 77kB
                     ->  Index Only Scan using tbl2_pkey on tbl2 prd  (cost=0.00..64.82 rows=2171 width=4) (actual time=0.021..0.537 rows=2171 loops=1)
                           Heap Fetches: 0
 Total runtime: 2268.394 ms
(17 rows)
```

Have query which select data from this view and runtime is also 2658.875 ms

```
SELECT view1."rsrv_qty",view1."comment",view1."rch_qty",view1."sequence",view1."order_id",
view1."qty",view1."uom_id",view1."categ_id",view1."mat_ids",view1."date_rchqty",
view1."par_id",view1."mt_id",view1."state",view1."orig_qty",view1."tracking_id",
view1."lbl_id",view1."date_qty",view1.id 
FROM "view1" 
WHERE view1.id IN (271053, 271054) 
ORDER BY id
```

Is there any way to optimize it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking it to do a lot of work.  I wouldn't count on getting it too much faster than what you currently have, no matter what effort you put into it (maybe a factor of 2, I doubt a factor of 10).

If you need a big improvement, you should consider whether you need absolutely up to date results at all times.  If not, you could use materialized views so that the query is only run once a minute or so.  You can either roll your own, or you can upgrade to 9.3 where native materialized views were introduced.

If you go back to your original query, perhaps it would be faster if you injected a where clause like:

```
where (lbl.mt_id, lbl.uom_id, lbl.tracking_id) in 
(select distinct mt_id, uom_id, tracking_id from tbl2 where id IN (271053, 271054))
```

But, maybe it wouldn't be faster.  And even if it is, I don't see how it could 
be made to work with a nice clean view, you would have to craft the query yourself.

The theory here is any row from tbl2 whose mt_id, uom_id and tracking_id don't coexist with one of the two tbl2.id you care about cannot contribute to the selected end result, because their min(lbl.id) cannot possible have a value other than from the set they coexist with.